# Using signature_pad with bootstrap modal and ajax saving

Tags: jquery, ajax, signaturepad

Using [this code](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) to plug a signature block into a form.
Using a standard HTML form, this works great (ie, a non-ajax call, but a form submitting to a URL).

But what I am now trying to do, is have the canvas in a bootstrap modal element on the page, which is initially hidden.
I then set the modal to show, and initiate the canvas.
Then - when the form (including the filled signature) is submitted - the form data is saved via `ajax` (jQuery).

My issue is that I keep getting errors relating to the canvas/signaturePad  not being defined - `signaturePad is not defined` when triggering the ajax save.

This is the signature code, included in the bootstrap `modal`:

```
 <div id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad">
    <div class="signature-pad--body">
      <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is the jQuery code, for when I launch the modal (which works perfectly - I can sign on the canvas):

```
       $("#ModalActionCost").modal('show');

       var wrapper = document.getElementById("signature-pad");
        var canvas = wrapper.querySelector("canvas");
        var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas, {
          backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
        });
```

And this is the code when I save the form contents:

```
    $("#trigger").click(function(e){

        var dataURL = signaturePad.toDataURL();   <-- this is the line I get the error on.
        $("#hiddenSignature").val(signaturePad.toDataURL("image/png").replace("data:image/png;base64,", ""));

        var hiddenSignature = $("#hiddenSignature").val();
        // ajax call follows.
        ......
   });
```

Again the error I am getting is: **`signaturePad is not defined`**

To try get around this error, I thought I need to initiate the canvas again (call `var signaturePad...`) when  saving via ajax - which did indeed work, and the pad blob value was sent - but of course I get a blank canvas, seen as it's been wiped when re define.

I put together a simplified version of the flow of jsfiddle - which DOES seem to work [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/L6oqhnj9/), but i cant figure out why my version above does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution, for others:

Move the instance of creating the signature_pad - from the function that opens the modal - to `onload` of the page in general:

```
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("signature-pad");
    var canvas = wrapper.querySelector("canvas");
    var signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas, {
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what's exactly happning with your code, but here is what you can do to solve it.

check your wrapper and canvas vars, see if they're undefined or null using `console.log(wrapper);` same to the canvas. 
if they're actually having values, then in your code, the `signaturePad` variable might be overwritten before the click trigger, or it's unreachable from within the click event (out of scope).

what I suggest to solve it is to give an id to the canvas itself :

```
<canvas id="SignaturePadCanvas"></canvas>
```

then do this :

```
const canvas  = document.querySelector("#SignaturePadCanvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
const signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas, {
          backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
        });

$("#trigger").click(function(e){

    if(signaturePad == null || signaturePad == undefined)
    {
        console.log(canvas); //  debuging 
        return alert('signaturePad is undefined');
    }

    var dataURL = signaturePad.toDataURL();   

    if (_signature.isEmpty()) {      
      return alert("cannot get the data of an empty signature");
    }   

    $("#hiddenSignature").val(signaturePad.toDataURL("image/png").replace("data:image/png;base64,", ""));

    var hiddenSignature = $("#hiddenSignature").val();

});
```